# Database design 101

Tags: database-design

I have a very basic question regarding the design of a database. I thought I knew the answer, but after seeing an online tutorial on a triple dropdown menu and the design of the demo database, I'm not so sure anymore.

Ok here's the setup, there are three tables involved.

First table: tblcountry
Fields: country_id
country

Second table: tblstate
Fields: state_id
country_id
state

Third table: tblcity
Fields: cidy_id
state_id
city

Now my question is: In table three, is it necessary to include the countryid as well? By using SQL you can query which country the city is in....or is it good design to have a reference to the country in the city table??

I hope someone can help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalization starts with *data*.  In what follows, take the word *state* loosely. I'm talking about data analysis and normalization, not about modeling political hierarchies.

```
country_name               state_name  city_name
--
United States of America   Alabama     Birmingham
United States of America   California  Atascadero
United States of America   Florida     Key Largo
United States of America   Illinois    Carbondale
United States of America   Kentucky    Winchester
United States of America   Michigan    St. Louis
United States of America   Ohio        Coldwater
United States of America   Montana     Glasgow
United States of America   Louisiana   Jefferson
United States of America   Wisconsin   Jefferson
Bulgaria                   Montana     Montana
Costa Rica                 San José    San José
Argentina                  Entre Rios  San José
Uruguay                    San José    San José de Mayo
```

It means "City [city_name] is in state [state_name] of country [country_name]."  (What a table means is called its predicate.)

This table  effectively identifies the "full name" of a city as {country_name, state_name, city_name}. At the conceptual level, it's not very different from using {last_name, middle_name, first_name} to identify a person. The difference is that, although two people often do share the same full name, two cities don't.

It's clear there's only one candidate key: {country_name, state_name, city_name}. This table is in 5NF. Substituting ID numbers for text can't change that.

Now, what's the *first* thing you think *after* you've normalized a table to 5NF, and that table turns out to be "all key"? Is it, "Ok, *now* I need to split the *key* into more tables?"

I hope not.

To increase data integrity, you can [project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28relational_algebra%29) sensible subsets of the columns, and set foreign key references.  Projection, used in this way, has absolutely no effect on the normal form of the original table.  If it were in 2NF before this kind of projection, it will be in 2NF after this kind of projection.  These tables have slightly different predicates from the original. (Duh.)

```
-- Predicate: "State [state_name] is in country [country_name]."
-- This table is also in 5NF.
create table states (
  country_name varchar(35) not null,
  state_name varchar(15) not null,
  primary key (country_name, state_name)
);

insert into states
select distinct country_name, state_name
from cities;

alter table cities
add constraint cities_fk1
foreign key (country_name, state_name)
  references states (country_name, state_name);

-- Predicate: "[country_name] is a country."
-- This table is also in 5NF.
create table countries (
  country_name varchar(35) primary key
);

insert into countries
select distinct country_name 
from states;

alter table states
add constraint states_fk1
foreign key (country_name)
  references countries (country_name);
```

To select countries for populating a drop-down list, you can just

```
select country_name
from countries
order by country_name;
```

The user having chosen a country, selecting states is simple.

```
select state_name
from states
where country_name = '?'
order by state_name;
```

And choosing city names is similar.

```
select city_name 
from cities
where country_name = '?' 
  and state_name = '?'
order by city_name;
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but in the table you show in the beginning, what if one of the states had 2 city_name values?  The way you set it up it seems logical that it should not be normalized further, but if one were to take it further and add more data, it would need to have one more table?  Or am I wrong?  I am very new to all this :-)

Comment: @user1088537: The key is {country_name, state_name, city_name}; you can have any number of distinct city names in a given state. That table *doesn't* allow two cities of the same name in one state. I've been working with addresses in SQL databases for 25 years; I've never seen two cities of the same name in one state. (I *have* seen two named places of the same name in one state. They're not the same thing.)

Answer (score 6):

Short answer, correct 99.9% of the time: No. You already have the reference to the country via the state record.

Long answer, for the 0.1% of the time: You may need to make a direct reference to the country from the city because you have a lot of queries for the cities of a country, and adding a second table to the query will make the query take much longer.

Granted this second scenario is not likely for record sets of cities, states, and countries, but for other types of data it is likely if you are managing a lot of records.

EDIT: In my job, I have a lot of these situations where I just keep extra fields in tables three or four levels of reference down. These are huge databases, and putting intermediate tables in all the common queries really stresses the database (much more memory used per query).  so I would start with no direct references, and then add "shortcut" fields as needed. This gets into the issue of solving the scalability problem, and that is way beyond a beginner level problem.  Also, if you add shortcut fields in downstream tables, then that is additional breaking point for your app (two records to update when you update a city to another country), and so keep that in mind as well.

Comment: Thanks!  That's what I thought and what I could surmise from all the books I've looked this up in.  It just really confused me to see this setup in a tutorial lol.  Just shows how solid my database design knowledge is ;-)

Answer (score 3):

> In table three, is it necessary to include the countryid as well?

No

You can get the county_id using the following query:

```
SELECT country_id 
FROM tblcity c
INNER JOIN tblstate s ON (c.state_id = s.state_id)
```

If you **do** include the `country_id` in the city table your database violates normal form, because data is duplicated and the danger is that data will get out of sync. E.g. what happens when the `country_id` in `tableCity` does not match with that in `tableState`.

If you want to get the country name, you'll need to join the country in as well:

```
SELECT co.country
FROM tblcity ci
INNER JOIN tblstate s ON (ci.state_id = s.state_id)
INNER JOIN tblCountry co ON (s.country_id = co.country_id)
```

Also note that the division: `city-> state -> country` is a very US centric view, not all countries are divided like that, in some countries you need four levels of hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks!  That confirms my suspicion.  I knew I could create a view combining all 3 tables if necessary, but seeing this setup I saw confused me quite a lot.  

I'm actually working on a database with farm names, so these tables do fit my needs up to a point.  The two first tables will be as simple as the first two table in question here, but my "city" table will contain more fields such as gps coordinates.